Hessian of the softmax function
Problem
Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and consider a softmax function $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Find representation of the Hessian of $f=\mathbf{c}^\top \sigma (\mathbf{x})$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, namely,
$$
(\mathbf{H}_f)_{i,j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \frac{\partial^2 \left(\mathbf{c}^\top \sigma (\mathbf{x})\right)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
$$


Try
First, it's intuitive to find the gradient,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} &= \left( \frac{\partial \sigma(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{c} \\
&= \mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{c}
\end{align}
where the Jacobian $\mathbf{J} = \mathrm{diag}\sigma(\mathbf{x}) - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \sigma(\mathbf{x})^\top$ by the property of softmax function.

Now, let $\mathbf{j}_1, \cdots, \mathbf{j}_n$ the columns of $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{c} := \left[ c_1, \cdots, c_n \right]^\top$.  Then the second-order derivative is given as follows.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right)  &= \left( \frac{\partial \mathbf{J}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{c} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \cdot  \frac{ \partial \mathbf{j}_k }{\partial \mathbf{x}}
\end{align}
Note $\mathbf{j}_k= \sigma_k(\mathbf{x}) \cdot  \left(\mathbf{e}_k - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \right)$, where $\sigma_k(\mathbf{x})$ is the $k$-th element of $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ and $\mathbf{e}_k$ the "standard basis" or one-hot vector where only $k$-th element is one and zero elsewhere. Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{ \partial \mathbf{j}_k }{\partial \mathbf{x}}  &= \frac{ \partial \left[ \sigma_k(\mathbf{x}) \cdot  \left(\mathbf{e}_k - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \right) \right]}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \\
&= \frac{ \partial \sigma_k(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot \left(\mathbf{e}_k - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \right)^\top + \sigma_k(\mathbf{x}) \cdot  \left( \frac{ \partial \left(\mathbf{e}_k - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \right)}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right)^\top \\
&= \mathbf{j}_k \cdot \left(\mathbf{e}_k - \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \right)^\top - \sigma_k(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{J}
\end{align}
Plugging this $\frac{ \partial \mathbf{j}_k }{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ into the above second-order derivative expression seems somewhat complicated. Can we further simplify the expression?
Thanks!

Why not write out the expression explicitly for $n=2$? You will easily see how to generalize the result.

I have always found it simplest to exploit some basic algebraic relationships, which are clarified by choosing a simple notation.
To this end, let the arguments $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be implicit -- I won't write them out when the context indicates they are present -- and define the "softmax" function components as $\sigma = \sigma(\mathbf x) = (p_1(\mathbf x), \ldots, p_n(\mathbf x))$ where the components are given by
$$p_i = p_i(\mathbf x) = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}}.$$
Since the exponentials are all positive this is well-defined for all $\mathbf x$ and the $p_i$ sum constantly to $1,$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1.\tag{1}$$

That's the first algebraic relation.
Using basic rules of univariate differentiation, compute

$$p_{i,j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} p_i = -e^{x_j} \frac{e^{x_i}}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}\right)^2} = -p_ip_j\tag{2}$$

for $j \ne i.$
That's the second algebraic relation -- and it's the only derivative you will need to compute.  Exploit the first relation and the sum rule of derivatives to find
$$0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\sum_{j=1}^n p_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^n p_{j,i} = p_{i,i} + \sum_{j\ne i} p_{j,i},$$
whence

$$p_{i,i} = -\sum_{j\ne i} p_{j,i}.\tag{3}$$

That's the third algebraic relation.
These relations express the first derivatives of all the components $p_i$ in terms of the $p_i$ themselves.  Thus, successive derivatives can be mechanically found iteratively.  To illustrate, the second derivatives are obtained from the second relation as

$$p_{i,jk} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} p_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} p_{i,j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (-p_ip_j) = -p_i p_{j,k} - p_{i,k}p_j\tag{*}$$

and the derivatives on the right hand side are available in $(2)$ and $(3)$ as polynomials in the $p_i.$
Finally, the question asks about the Hessian of a linear combination
$$\mathbf c^\prime \sigma(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\, p_i.$$
Taking second derivatives we immediately obtain, with no further labor,

$$H_{jk} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} \mathbf c^\prime \sigma(\mathbf x) = \pmatrix{p_{1,jk} & p_{2,jk}& \cdots & p_{n,jk}}\mathbf c = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \,p_{i,jk},$$

all of whose values are given by $(*).$
Not only is this conceptually and notationally efficient, it leads to an efficient algorithm for computing the Hessian, too.  Thus, there's usually no point to exploiting the relationships $(1)-(3)$ further to express $H_{jk}$ more explicitly as a polynomial in the $p_i.$  This, then, constitutes the requested "representation" of $H_{jk}.$

There are existing computational facilities for the softmax function
The answer by whuber gives you a parsimonious expression of the Hessian of the linear combination of softmax elements.  It may also be worth noting that the softmax function, inverse-softmax function, log-softmax function, and log-inverse-softmax function are all programmed in the utilities package in R.  These functions include computation of the gradient and Hessian.
Here is an example using a problem in $n=6$ dimensional space with $\mathbf{x} = (-2, 1, 2, 0, 3)$ (with the first element implicitly zero) and $\mathbf{c} = (0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2)$.  In the code below we first compute the softmax function at the stipulated value of $\mathbf{x}$, including its gradient and Hessian, and we then compute the linear combination of elements of the softmax function, including its gradient and Hessian.
#Compute the softmax function with gradient and Hessian included
x    <- c(-2, 1, 2, 0, 3)
SOFT <- utilities::softmax(x, lambda = 1, gradient = TRUE, hessian = TRUE)
GRAD <- attributes(SOFT)$gradient
HESS <- attributes(SOFT)$hessian

#Compute the Hessian of the linear combination of softmax elements
c    <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2)
LINSOFT <- sum(c*SOFT)
GRAD2   <- rep(0, 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
  GRAD2[i] <- sum(c*GRAD[ , i]) }
HESS2   <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
for (j in 1:5) {
  HESS2[i, j] <- sum(c*HESS[ , i, j]) } }
attr(LINSOFT, 'gradient') <- GRAD2  
attr(LINSOFT, 'hessian')  <- HESS2

#Show the linear combination of softmax elements with gradient and Hessian included
LINSOFT
[1] 0.1176882
attr(,"gradient")
[1] -7.404799e-05  6.921096e-03 -4.042883e-03  5.639403e-03 -1.098970e-02
attr(,"hessian")
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
[1,] -7.342802e-05 -2.274748e-05  3.384937e-05 -2.131767e-05  9.201212e-05
[2,] -2.274748e-05  5.757190e-03 -1.241970e-03 -6.882714e-04 -3.376025e-03
[3,]  3.384937e-05 -1.241970e-03 -2.194770e-03 -1.163905e-03  5.023692e-03
[4,] -2.131767e-05 -6.882714e-04 -1.163905e-03  5.290518e-03 -3.163823e-03
[5,]  9.201212e-05 -3.376025e-03  5.023692e-03 -3.163823e-03  2.666114e-03

